# Android Passpoint

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I'm researching a way for an APP to have integrated piece of data allowing users to connect seamlessly to WiFi via passpoint hotspot. I'm aware that connecting via passpoint is suppose to be seamless however it is important that connecting to this particular WiFi can only be done with the app installed.

EDIT: Also is there a way to integrate required data in the app so that users can with a click of a button first time register in passpoint/hotspot2.0 WLAN?

I've looked online on some of the information regarding passpoint but this one thing is still an unknown to me.

Is it possible to create something like that?
If so could any of you helping souls provide some materials?

Thanks!